# MFC TRY CATCH macro in thread causes memory leak

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, visual-studio-2015

I have a simple try catch block in a function:

```
TRY
{
    ; // Doesn't matter what is in the try block, I got memory leak just for a simple semicolon!
}
CATCH( COleException, e )
{
    return e->m_sc;
}
END_CATCH
```

This code always run in new threads (using _beginthread), threads may created multiple times, but the threads' life is very short.

Using the MFC TRY/CATCH macros cause a massive memory leak. Removing the try catch fix the leak immediately.

Using vs 2015 diagnostic tool I compared memory snapshots, and found that the leaking types are:
_AFX_THREAD_STATE and CThreadData

What is the reason for this leak using try/catch mfc macros?

Comment: How are you creating those threads? Are you using MFC facilities for that? I suspect that you don't, and that using `AfxBeginThread` or similar would set up and tear down per-thread state properly.

Comment: Thanks. The code use only _beginthread. AfxBeginThread may fix, but would be overkill to modify existing thread handling. I've already fixed this by removing the TRY/CATCH macros (handling error codes instead) or converting to "normal" try/catch

Answer (score 0):

If you have a return in the CATCH block, END_CATCH will not delete the COleException object.

It's good practice to abandon the TRY/CATCH macros anyway:

```
try 
{
    ...
}
catch (COleException* pe) 
{
    SCODE sc = pe->m_sc;
    pe->Delete();
    return sc;
}
```

Comment: The MFC CATCH macro creates pointers, so that is no problem, here is the first line of the exception:
#define CATCH(class, e) } catch (class* e) \  ....